# Why is my sub-surf modifier acting up?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

The sub-surf modifier is causing a weird indent around the end of my sleeve right next to where I have the sleeve thicken a little and I was wondering why it was causing that and what I can do to fix it?  [image]

Comment: looks like flipped normals in that area

Comment: see this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12165/make-all-of-the-faces-flip-to-the-right-direction

Comment: It was my normals on hidden geometry.  I had tried flipping the normals automatically and manually earlier and it didn't help, but after reading your comments I decided to try again and I found some hidden faces I didn't realize had been created and they were backwards.  THANKS!!