# How to flip normals to avoid backface culling for all the model not just 1 side

Tags: uv, blender-internal-render-engine, normals

I have a strange problem. I modeled and textured some plane using UV mapping which I modified and extruded a lot. Now when I render it from different angles, I have transparent meshes in different sides of the model.

When I do *Mesh > Flip Normals*, it flipped all the faces which previous looking transparent and now they look textured.

So how I make my mesh consistent and without transparent faces?

Here is the images after flipping normals:

[image]

And this is after:  see the back of the model now is transparent
[image]

Comment: Did you try *recalculating* normals by `Ctrl`+`N` (with all selected) ? This should make them facing the same direction regardless how they were directed before. If this doesn't help I'm afraid you'll need to flip individual normals by hand.

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12165/make-all-of-the-faces-flip-to-the-right-direction