# Mirror modifier deforms mesh

Tags: mesh, modifiers

[image]

Whenever I apply mirror modifier to my mesh the mirrored part becomes deformed and wrinkled as shown in the image. I exported the mesh as obj and opened it in another window and tried to mirror it again but the same thing still happens. How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance

.blend file:

[image]

Comment: Your mesh has custom split normals data. Mirror modifier most likely can't mirror it correctly. Remove the data and work with Mirror modifier; you'll add data if needed further on. See - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47291/mirror-modifier-making-ugly-smoothing-on-mirrored-faces

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you must *Apply* the modifier. To do this, Click the *Apply* button. When I downloaded the file, I did not see any disturbances in rendered view. If you are still having them, consider going to *File > External Data* and check *Automatically Pack Into .blend* before uploading. This will allow me to view the file **with** the textures. I will update my answer as needed.