# An object broken when it's rendered

Tags: rendering

I have a weird error to render images. when I see the object with rendered view it is ok but only when I do real rendering part of the model is broken. Do anyone know how I can fix this?

[image: rendered image]
[image: rendered view]

Comment: You may have a duplicate set of mesh (your walls) that are hidden. With your cursor in the viewport press ALT + "H" to unhide objects. Or you can look in the Outliner to make sure all the "Eye" icons are on.

Comment: try [recalculating normals](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/12165/2217).

Comment: Do you have any modifier on the "broken" object? I would guess, from the shape assumed in rendered version, that is being "subsurfed" by catmul-clark.

Comment: I had modifier by accident and didn't notice about it at all as you guessed, thank you very much, now I could render without that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As one comment pointed out there seems to be a subsurface modifier active on the mesh making up the wood part of your house.

As you can filter if and how many iterations the modifier should apply, depending on whether it is a render or just the viewport, you should check in the modifier panel while having the wood mesh selected if any of this holds true.

[image: Example settings]

The camera icon in the header means this modifier is active in the final render and the eye icon means that this modifier is active in the viewport.

In the example screenshot from the modifier the subdivisions are set to one (1) for the viewport and two (2) for the final render.

Comment: Yes you were right, I didn't notice I had the modifier, I don't know when I added by accident so didn't realise at all. Thank you very much, you saved me!!