# Boolean not working as expected

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I am trying to get the text (Date) to inscribe onto the base but when I apply the Boolean modifier it the result I get isn't as  expected.

Here are the images of the problem meshes:

1. Clarifying that they are seperate objects
   [image: image of letters and base as separate objects]
2. The boolean modifyer and the shapes together
   [image: image of letters and base together]
3. After effects of applying boolean
   [image: result after applying Boolean]

Comment: Booleans can be tricky sometimes. But it's hard to tell what kind of geometry you have in the input and output meshes without wireframe screenshots. Generally make your substractive object invisible to better preview the results of boolean. Try nudging it a bit or increasing subdivisions of the base and you might get better results. BTW you do know about the text object in Blender that you usually use to create 3D text?

Comment: First off, inverted normals on letters except for 'y' and '6'. And they are the only ones more or less visible in the result. So [make them consistent](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12165/how-to-make-all-faces-flip-to-the-right-consistent-direction) via `Ctrl`+`N`.Then, most likely geometry of the base is not enough subdivided. Make it more dense.