# Visible seam on the mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have started to model a torso. I was happy with it, until I discovered the seam in the mid of the mesh. I have not used the mirror modifier at all, what else could it be?

[image: model with seam]

[image: mesh in edit mode]

Comment: Not enough information. Could you add a screenshot in edit mode, and one of the modifier stack?

Comment: I edited the OP

Answer (score 2):

It seems that half of the normals in your model are inverted (the normals of some faces are facing inward and some outward). This might be causing display problems.

Go to `Edit Mode`, select all faces and use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate normals.

If recalculating the normals doesn't help, display face normals as lines, select only the faces with normals facing inward, and flip normals on those faces.

Comment: Happy I could help :)

Comment: You shold accept Karolinas answere. :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your main issue is that you have some geometry hidden in the middle. Then the subdivision modifier is taking those hidden faces into account and making the crease.
I would recommend trying the "Select Non Manifold" tool, found from the 3D view header *Select* > *Non Manifold*, or the very covenant keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>. Then set it to only select the Boundaries in the operator properties part of the tool shelf.
[image: Select Non Manifold tool options]
But do not just delete what it selects, it will select the bottom and top loops of your mesh, you want to keep those.

If that does not help, try looking in wireframe shading, <kbd>Z</kbd> to toggle between solid and wireframe, for any gemotery that is not part of the outside mesh.

You also have half of the mesh's normals reversed (the dark part). Just select everything and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to fix that.
More info here: [How to make all faces flip to the right/consistent direction?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/12165/2217)