# Center grooves with mirror and Subsurf Modifiers

Tags: mirror, error

SOLVED BY SHADY PUCK = AN UNDELETED FACE IN THE CENTER

[image: Groove in Center]
[image: Subsurf & OpenSubdiv]
[image: Delete Inward Face]

Delete that face & Reapply Modifiers

Comment: Could you clarify what the question is? Please edit your post and provide more details about what you are trying to do and what failed.

Comment: I'm thinking this is just a problem with the order of the modifiers. Hit the arrow on the side of the Mirror modifier to push it up the stack to make it first before the subsurf modifier.

Comment: related links: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52181/weird-line-in-my-mirrored-mesh and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6063/subsurf-and-mirror-modifier-creating-a-split-in-mesh and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33996/multiresolution-subdivide-modifier-on-a-mirrored-surface-causes-a-visible-seam and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61347/visible-seam-on-the-mesh

Comment: How is this related to OpenSubdiv Compute and GLSL compute? No need to reinstall anything, this won't fix Mirror modifier

Comment: The Mirror Modifier was already applied and I already tried re ordering Modifiers before applying, but I didn't try applying the Subsurf first then Mirror. If your wondering what OpenSubdiv Compute & GLSL Compute have to do is that in image 3 OpenSubdiv is checked and there is an open in Preferences > System > OpenSubdiv GLSL

Comment: @ Mr.Zak in Image 3 OpenSubdiv doesn't fix Mirror Modifier, it fixes the Subsurf Modifier