# Why faces have a dark texture? Already recalculated normals

Tags: normals, unity, mirror

When I imported this model into Unity a few parts of the model seem to be inside out. (the wings and the left engine)

[image]

I opened the model in blender, selected the relevant components, and recalculated normals. Now nothing is inside out.

[image]

However you can see that those parts are now really dark. And I can't fix this.

[image]

The problem itself can be seen in blender as dark faces. Similar to the problem seen when faces are inverted.

I have already tried:

- recalculating normals on all components (the rest are unchanged)
- checking that the normals actually ARE facing outwards by showing the weights of the normal
- checking that both parts share the same material

why are these faces darker? how can I fix it?

Comment: No I have already used this answer. I have recalculated the normal's already.

Comment: Did you try the various options in the second answer?

Comment: please consider uploading your model to blendexchange (https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). Your issue is 100% caused by non-conform normals. Your screenshot shows that parts of the wings normals point inward. Sometimes, recalculating doesn't address all areas. Depending on your geometry, you need to flip areas by hand. Also negative scale on the object itself can affect the normals during export. But that would flip the whole object

Comment: I cannot upload the model, it is a paid model.

Comment: Are you sure that you have applied a material to those sections?

Comment: It looks like those sections of the model do not have a Material assigned to them.

Comment: You still do have a normal issue (all your pictures show it). [How to make all faces flip to the right/consistent direction?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/12174/2217)

Comment: I have solved the problem. The questions marked as duplicates DID NOT help. My problem is similar to those marked as duplicate, but that DID NOT solve it as stated in the TITLE OF THE QUESTION.

I needed to press the "Set From Faces" button to fix it after recalculating normals. I have no clue what this function does but it worked. Thanks for those who tried helping.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't upload your model, I will try to point out the problems with your plane based on your screenshots. As stated in the comments, your issue is caused by flipped normals. You also have overlaying geometry, that can be caused by

1. duplication of the object at the exact same spot of the original mesh
2. duplication of all faces "inside" (in Editmode) of the objects

One of the objects has normals facing inwards, the other object faces outward. That explains why the normals *are* consistent, but *look* inconsistent. Find the Object or faces that point inwards (dark blue) and delete them or move them to another layer.

There were also some additional issues with your model, they are not part of the question but I want to point them out anyways.

[image: duplication, z-fighting, mirror modifier problems]

- faulty mirror modifier: (sorry for the typo in the screenshot)
  the mirror axis is off, you have intersecting geometry on your Y-axis
- there are several places with poor topology. I would suggest you to remodel parts of the object with cleaner topology. I hope you didn't pay too much for this model, its quality isn't very good.

if you want me to take a closer look, send the file to ian.smith[ätt]posteo[dott]de