# What´s wrong with my (glitchy) render?

Tags: rendering, mesh

[image]

[image]

So i am working on a little funproject. Everything seemed fine in the preview, but than the render turned out quite strange. I should further explain. Those object´s which turned ok are ones that actually are seperate. The ground mesh is a subdivided plane with some downwards extruded squares. It has the same material as everything else (except the lights). Why is it white and glitchy in the render?

Comment: it is called z-fighting. Follow the link of  RayMairlot to solve the issue. You most likely have a second ground plane in your scene, that is invisible for viewport rendering but visible for final rendering.

Comment: Recalcuate the normals https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/12174/2217.

Comment: It actually was a hidden plane. Should have checked that. Won´t happen again!