# Problems with Texturing in Blender Game Engine

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, game-engine

Posting this question again and maybe I'll find any help this time. So, recently I was trying to port model from Mass Effect, this model is a helmet on the image below.[image]

So, the problem is that I had to apply the texture on it using Blender Game Engine, not the cycles or Blender Render. And the outcome after UV mapping the helmet resulted in this:[image][image]
Can someone please tell me what I had to do to get rid of it? I am just losing hope atm. It worked fine in the Cycles but not in the Blender Game engine.

Any pieces of advice would be helpful!

Comment: Is backface Culling on?

Comment: "*Can someone please tell me what I had to do to get rid of it?*" Get rid of what exactly? I'm not sure it is very clear what you are asking, could you please clarify?

Comment: [How to make all faces flip to the right/consistent direction?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/12165/2217)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the images you posted, this is probably what's wrong with you scene.

**Flipped normals**

[image]

**Steps to fix:-**

> **1.** Select your object and go to edit mode
>
> **2.** Move over to the shadings and UV tab
>
> **3.** Select everything in your mesh
>
> **4.** Click on recalculate

[image]

> **5.** Go to properties panel and find the shading section and turn off **Backface culling**

**Explanation:-**

> What Backface culling does is cull or clip the back sides of the face, and the back side is determined by the normals. Your model, judging from the picture, has its normals flipped inside out, and you have backface culling on therefore it's culling all the backfaces. If recalculation does not work, then it means some of the faces are flipped unevenly, thus they need to be manually flipped by using the **Flip Direction** button in the same shading panel in the tools tab region.

Answer (score 0):

Hey got something for you!
You need to reverse the normals of the model.

Select the mesh and go into Edit Mode.  Select all of the mesh vertices by clicking the A key, click Mesh > Normals > Flip Normals. Go back into Object Mode and then you're set!