# Remove black lines rendered using Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Why are these black lines appearing in the render when I'm using Cycles? How can I remove them? Thanks!

[image]

Update: the object is not using textures and the problem persists. This screenshot shows the mesh.

How I created the model: I selected a face from the stones model, I separated the face with "p" -> Selection, then I extruded it, I removed the old texture assignation, however a new object like a box is clear, so it seems there's a "link" with old parameters taken from the separation.

[image: image2]

Update 2:

This is what happens if I create a new texture, with an image and the UV unwrap.

[image: image3]

Update 3:

I created a new scene, I pasted there the object and the problem persists. Then I do the following:

- Cursor to Center
- Selection to Cursor
- Geometry to origin

Guess what? The lines disappear. The problem is not fixed because I don't want the object at the center of the workspace. It's for a big scene, about 400 m x 500 m.

Comment: could you please share the object?

Comment: Please update your questions with additional information regarding how the material nodes, whether you're using UVs, the UV map - anything that might help determine the problem.

Comment: The way the lines are shaped definitely looks like a texture forgotten somewhere. Baked lighting perhaps?

Comment: Or bad mapping. Try a generated or object mapping instead of UV (default) or unwrap to get new UV

Comment: i had a similar problem [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/136811/11431) with the same kind of fix (change of origin and back to world origin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: select the object, and then select the option:

Object -> Transform -> Origin to Geometry.

This solution is similar to the @Bithur's comment.

I don't know why it happens, but it seems Blender could have a little bug about handling textures when the objects are too far from the workspace center. For sure it's not a feature.