# Why Cycles renders some faces black?

Tags: rendering

I have imported a model as obj. from rhino to blender. When i use the Cycles render, some faces are black no matter which material i choose. I have already tried to flip the normals but that didnt work.
I also tried to delete a face when in edit mode and replace it with an extruded edge but that doesnt fix the prblem either. I can only delete the faces and replace them with planes in obj mode.
Here are some pictures of the problem.
[image][image]

Also in material preview mode some models appear with a gradient on them.[image]

Comment: overlapping faces? clear custom split normals data?

Comment: no overlapping faces. i didnt know about the 2nd one but i found that button under geometry data and hit it but didnt fix the problem. Is that what you meant?

Comment: yes that's what I meant, maybe share a part of your file where we can see the problem: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/9a441f0b245348d3960ad5258dc6bff7
 take a look if you can

Comment: Those issues are caused by two things Z-fight https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-do-i-avoid-rendering-glitches-from-overlapping-faces and wrong Face orientation https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12165/how-to-make-all-faces-flip-to-the-right-consistent-direction ... and because Face orientation is bigger issue here I voted as dupli of FO.