# Exported Blender file to Roblox studio looks hollow

Tags: export, external-applications

I've been trying to get this scythe I made to work in Roblox studio but whenever I add any of my blender things it ends up looking like this. It comes out looking hollow I guess.

[image]

[image]

Comment: you forgot the screenshot?

Comment: Also the 'blender-osm' tag that you've used has nothing whatever to do with your question. Change it to 'export' to match the subject of your question.

Comment: We'll need more details than that! What does it look like in Blender?

Comment: Sorry for all the flaws, i have no clue on what im doing.

Comment: Game engines do not draw the back of faces for performance reasons (so-called "backface culling"). When your added "blender things" (the grip surfaces around the handle?) look "hollow" then the faces are probably flipped ("flipped normals"). Check them with the [face orientation overlay](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/167034/107598). Red is bad.